# Valid iterator on a removed list?

Tags: java, iterator, pass-by-value

I wrote some code that works but I'm not sure. Consider

```
LinkedList<Iterator<Integer>> iterators;
HashMap<Character, TreeSet<Integer>> map;
for (char c : map.keySet()) {
    iterators.add(map.get(c).iterator());
    map.remove(c);
}
```

Even though the original TreeSet has been removed, the iterator seems to work fine (i.e. goes in the original ordering of the TreeSet). I don't quite understand why it's functional--it seems as though there's passing-by-value here instead of passing-by-reference. However, obviously, if I were to write

```
map.get(c).add(6);
```

the TreeSet would actually add 6 in the map (not just add 6 to a copy of the TreeSets in the map), indicating get is passing by reference. Can someone help clear up the confusion here?

Comment: What relation does an `Iterator` from a `TreeSet` have to a `HashMap`?

Answer (score 1):

Removing the `TreeSet` from the `HashMap` doesn't destroy the `TreeSet`; it just removes the reference in the `HashMap` to the `TreeSet`.  The `HashMap` doesn't contain a copy of the `TreeSet`, just a reference to the `TreeSet`.

At first:

```
{map} -----> {aTreeSet}
                  |
                  v
                 {6}
```

The `Iterator`'s purpose is to iterate over something.  In this case, the logical way for it to iterate over the `TreeSet` elements is to maintain its own reference to the `TreeSet` (or an internal data structure within the `TreeSet`).  The elements are always referred to by at at least one strong reference, so they are never garbage collected.

When the `Iterator` is created:

```
{map} -----> {aTreeSet} <----- {Iterator}
                  |
                  v
                 {6}
```

After removal from the map (and the addition to the `LinkedList`):

```
{map}        {aTreeSet} <----- {Iterator} <----- {iterators}
                  |
                  v
                 {6}
```

To summarize, the `TreeSet` elements are never eligible for garbage collection; there is only one `TreeSet` object, and the elements of it are still available for iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I read your post 5 times and I can't still get where's the confusion?

You're asking why after removing entry from `Map` you still have working `iterator` in `iterators`? That's how references in Java works...

Line:

```
iterators.add(map.get(c).iterator());
```

creates new strong reference to `TreeSet` which is under `c`, so this `set` won't be gced.

When it comes to pass-by-reference vs. pass-by-value - there is nothing like *true pass-by-reference* known from C/C++. For details look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

When it comes to line:

```
map.get(c).add(6);
```

I have no clue what do you mean by

> the TreeSet would actually add 6 in the map (not just add 6 to a copy of the TreeSets in the map)

what do you mean by *copy of the TreeSets in map*? Copy of what? It points to the same `TreeSet` as `iterator` from `iterators` points at.